# How to pass the parameters from directive to function in controller using Angular Js 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass the `resourceManagerGrid` to that `resourceManagerAddPage` function because when I submit my data I want to see those reflected changes get reloaded on that page. But when I am trying to pass `$scope.resourceManagerGrid` into that function using variable it is giving uncaught reference error `resourceManagerGrid undefined`.

Please please help me to find the solution.

```js
//Controller 
var resourceManagerSetUpApp = angular.module('resourceManagerSetUpApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ng-tb-common', 'ng-tb-tabbar', 'ng-tb-header', 'ng-tb-attribute', 'ng-tb-attribute-row', 'ng-tb-menubar', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'ngMaterial', 'ng-tb-ui-grid', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui.grid.treeView', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ng-tb-attribute-column', 'workTaskApp', 'requirementApp', 'documentApp']);

resourceManagerSetUpApp.controller('tabController', function($scope, TabLoaderService) {

  var c = this;
  c.tabConfiguration = [];
  c.tabConfiguration.tabs = [];
  var servicePromise = TabLoaderService.getTabConfiguration(tabconfig);
  servicePromise.then(function(data) {
    c.tabConfiguration = data.tabconfiguration;
  }, function() {
    $log.error('Could not receive tabs .')
  });

});

resourceManagerSetUpApp.controller('resourceManagerDetailController', function($scope, TBHttpService, FormLoaderService, resourceManagerCommonService, uiGridService, uiGridConstants)

  {
    var c = this;
    $scope.resourceManagerGrid = {};
    $scope.$on('resize::resize', function() {
      var dim = windowDimensions();
      c.pageHeight = {
        "max-height": "" + (dim[1] - 145) + "px",
        "min-height": "" + (dim[1] - 145) + "px"
      };
    });
    //This the function i want to pass my resourceManagerGrid
    fnOpenResManagerCreateEditPage = function(ev, data) {
      resourceManagerCommonService.resourceManagerAddPage(ev, data, $scope.resourceManagerGrid);
    }
  });

resourceManagerSetUpApp.directive('resourceManagerGrid', function(uiGridService, TBHttpService, $rootScope, $mdDialog) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "ngtb/resource/resourceManager/view/resourceManagerGrid.jsp",
    scope: {
      resorcetype: "@",
    },
    controller: function($scope, TBHttpService, $rootScope) {
      var dim = windowDimensions();
      $scope.loading = true;
      $scope.showGrid = false;
      // For Dynamically Changes height,width
      $scope.$on('resize::resize', function() {
        var dim = windowDimensions();
        $scope.gridHeight = {
          "max-height": "" + (dim[1] - 200) + "px",
          "min-height": "" + (dim[1] - 200) + "px",
          "max-width": "" + (dim[0] - 30) + "px",
          "min-width": "" + (dim[0] - 30) + "px",
        }
      });

      // set grid height
      $scope.resourceManagerGridHeightCal = function() {
        dim = windowDimensions();
        return {
          "max-height": "" + (dim[1] - 100) + "px",
          "min-height": "" + (dim[1] - 100) + "px",
          "max-width": "" + (dim[0] - 30) + "px",
          "min-width": "" + (dim[0] - 30) + "px",
        };

      };
      var resourceManagerConfig = angular.copy(tabconfig);

      // initialize Grid Data
      var extraParams = {};
      extraParams["resorceType"] = $scope.resorcetype;

      var actions = uiGridService.seturlParams("resourceAction.do", "buildResourceManagerGrid", "", extraParams);

      $scope.resourceManagerGrid = {};
      $scope.resourceManagerGrid.gridId = "resourceManagerGrid";
      $scope.isContantGrid = false;

      $rootScope.$on('uiGridService.reloadGrid', function() {
        $scope.showGrid = true;
        $scope.loading = false;
      });
      $rootScope.$on('uiGridService.Init', function() {
        $scope.showGrid = true;
        $scope.loading = false;
      });
      $scope.initGrid = function() {

        $scope.resourceManagerGrid = uiGridService.init($scope.resourceManagerGrid, '');
        //  $scope.loading=true;
      };
      $scope.initGrid();
    }
  }
});

resourceManagerSetUpApp.service('resourceManagerCommonService', ['TBHttpService', 'uiGridService', '$mdDialog', function(TBHttpService, uiGridService, $mdDialog, $log, $scope) {
  var resourceManagerCommonService = {

    resourceManagerAddPage: function(ev, data, scope) {
      $mdDialog.show({

        controller: 'resourceManagerCreateEditController',
        templateUrl: "ngtb/resource/resourceManager/view/addResourceManager.html",
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
        controllerAs: 'contrl',
        //actionForReload:
        locals: {
          objectInfoData: data
          //objectInfoData : $scope.resourceManagerGrid
        }
        // targetEvent: event,
      }).then(function(eventInfo) {
        if (eventInfo.resourceManagerGrid) {
          eventInfo.resourceManagerGrid(eventInfo);
        }
      }, function() {

      });
    },
  }
  return resourceManagerCommonService;
}]);

resourceManagerSetUpApp.controller('resourceManagerCreateEditController', function($scope, TBHttpService, FormLoaderService, $mdDialog, objectInfoData, FormValidationService, $window, $log, AttributeListRelationService) {
  var c = this;
  c.formData = [];
  var url = {};
  var dimesionData = {}
  $scope.Title = objectInfoData.mode;
  url.objectType = objectInfoData.objectType;
  url.formId = objectInfoData.formId;
  url.classId = objectInfoData.classId;
  var urlString = ResourceUtil.fnBuildRequestString(null, url, null);

  var dataUrlDefault = null;
  dataUrlDefault = "wbsAction.do?action=AngularFormBuilder&" + urlString;

  $scope.popupStyle = {
    "min-height": "" + (70) + "%",
    "min-width": "" + (80) + "%",
  };
  $scope.fnCancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };

  $scope.fnSubmit = function() {
    var servicePromise = true;

    if (servicePromise == true) {
      servicePromise = FormValidationService.fnFormMandatoryValidation(c.formData, $scope, true);
    }

    if (true == servicePromise) {

      if (objectInfoData.mode == "Create") {

        $scope.isFormDataLoaded = false;
        var myHash = {};
        myHash.objectType = objectInfoData.objectType;
        myHash.mode = objectInfoData.mode;
        myHash.classId = objectInfoData.classId
        var urlString = ResourceUtil.fnBuildRequestString(null, myHash, null);
        var url = "resorceManagerAction.do?action=saveManagerDetails&" + urlString;
        var dataPromise = TBHttpService.processRequest(url, 'POST', c.formData);
        dataPromise.then(function(response) {
          if (response.success) {
            var data = {};
            data.resourceManagerGrid = objectInfoData.resourceManagerGrid;
            data.objectId = response.objectId;
            $mdDialog.hide(data);
          }
          alert(response.message);
          $scope.isDataLoaded = true;
        }, function() {
          $log.error('Could not receive any data.')
        });

      } else if (objectInfoData.mode == "Edit") {

        $scope.isFormDataLoaded = false;
        var myHash = {};
        myHash.objectType = objectInfoData.objectType;
        myHash.mode = objectInfoData.mode;
        myHash.classId = objectInfoData.classId
        var urlString = ResourceUtil.fnBuildRequestString(null, myHash, null);
        var url = "resorceManagerAction.do?action=saveManagerDetails&" + urlString;
        var dataPromise = TBHttpService.processRequest(url, 'POST', c.formData);
        dataPromise.then(function(response) {
          if (response.success) {
            var data = {};
            data.resourceManagerGrid = objectInfoData.resourceManagerGrid;
            data.objectId = response.objectId;
            $mdDialog.hide(data);
          }
          alert(response.message);

        }, function() {
          $log.error('Could not receive any data.')
        });
      }
    };
  };
  $scope.getFormConfigData = function() {
    FormLoaderService.getFormConfiguration(objectInfoData, objectInfoData.mode, dataUrlDefault).then(function(data) {
      c.formData = data;
      /*$scope.dimesionData=data;
      $scope.dialogHeightWidh =data.dimensionData.popupStyle ;
      $scope.dialogPageHeight =data.dimensionData.contentStyle;
      AttributeListRelationService.fnFillAllChildList(c.formData,$scope);*/

    }, function() {
      $log.error('Could not receive tab details .')
    });
  }

  $scope.getFieldSetAttributeFromFormData = function(attrId, formData) {
    var attr = null;
    angular.forEach(c.formData.fieldsets, function(fieldset, index) {

      angular.forEach(fieldset.attributes, function(attribute, attrIndex) {
        if (attribute.attrId == attrId) {
          attr = attribute;
        }
      });
    });

    return attr;
  };

  $scope.$on('Attribute.OnChange', function(ev, attr, eventInfo) {

    var attrId = attr.attrId;
    var attrValue = attr.value;
    var userDateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    if (attrId == 'EFFECTIVE_TO_DATE') {
      var toDate = attrValue;
      var fromDateAttrObj = $scope.getFieldSetAttributeFromFormData('EFFECTIVE_FROM_DATE');
      var fromDate = DateUtil.fnGetDateFromString(userDateFormat, fromDateAttrObj.value);
      var toDate = DateUtil.fnGetDateFromString(userDateFormat, attr.value);
      if (toDate < fromDate) {
        attr.value = '';
        alert("Effective to date can not be less than from date.");
      }
    } else if (attrId == 'EFFECTIVE_FROM_DATE') {
      var toDate = attrValue;
      var fromDateAttrObj = $scope.getFieldSetAttributeFromFormData('EFFECTIVE_TO_DATE');
      var fromDate = DateUtil.fnGetDateFromString(userDateFormat, fromDateAttrObj.value);
      var toDate = DateUtil.fnGetDateFromString(userDateFormat, attr.value);
      if (toDate > fromDate) {
        attr.value = '';
        alert("Effective from date can not be gretter than to date.");
      }
    }
  });

  $scope.getFormConfigData();

  var dim = windowDimensions();
  // /set dimention of md-dialog box
  $scope.dialogHeightWidh = {
    "max-height": "" + ((80)) + "%",
    "min-width": "" + ((80)) + "%"
  };

  $scope.dialogPageHeight = {
    "max-height": "" + ((dim[1] * 0.8) - 110) + "px",
    "min-height": "" + ((dim[1] * 0.8) - 110) + "px",
    "height": "" + ((dim[1] * 0.8) - 110) + "px"
  };

  $scope.fullscreen = false;
  $scope.fnToggleScreenModal = function(showFullScreen) {
    var dim = windowDimensions();
    if (showFullScreen) {
      $scope.fullscreen = true;
      $scope.dialogHeightWidh = {
        "min-height": "" + ((99)) + "%",
        "min-width": "" + ((99)) + "%"
      };

      $scope.dialogPageHeight = {
        "max-height": "" + ((dim[1] * 1) - 105) + "px",
        "min-height": "" + ((dim[1] * 1) - 105) + "px",
        "height": "" + ((dim[1] * 1) - 105) + "px"
      };
    } else {
      $scope.fullscreen = false;
      $scope.dialogHeightWidh = {
        "max-height": "" + ((80)) + "%",
        "min-width": "" + ((80)) + "%"
      };

      $scope.dialogPageHeight = {
        "max-height": "" + ((dim[1] * 0.8) - 110) + "px",
        "min-height": "" + ((dim[1] * 0.8) - 110) + "px",
        "height": "" + ((dim[1] * 0.8) - 110) + "px"
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I want to paas the resourceManagerGrid to that resourceManagerAddPage funtion bcz when i submit my data i want to see those reflected changes gets reloaded on that page. But when i am trying to pass $scope.resourceManagerGrid into that function using variable it is giving uncaught reference error resourceManagerGrid undefined. Please please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function with $scope.resourceManagerGrid as third parameter. The definition has $scope as third parameter, and you try to get .resourceManagerGrid from it. So basically, you put $scope.resourceManagerGrid from the calling context in the $scope variable inside the function. And then you try to get the property $scope.resourceManagerGrid. So you try to get $scope.resourceManagerGrid.resourceManagerGrid, which does not exist.

Just call the function like you do, and change the 3rd parameter from $scope to resourceManagerGrid, then use it inside the function.